# Issues with executing multiple queries using Spark and HiveSQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Within spark-shell where if I attempt something like below:

```scala
var sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc) 

var query = "select * from myDB.table limit 10; drop table if exists"

var queryDF = sqlContext.sql(query)
```

I receive an error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnlysisException: missing EOF at ';'....
```

I can execute simple simple single line queries just fine but multi-command queries always result in this error.

Has anyone ran into and solved this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an expected behavior. `SQLContext.sql` doesn't support multiple queries so solution is pretty simple - pass only a single query at the time.

Comment: Is it a bug from Spark SQL parser? Because this is possible with Hive already.