# How to execute multiple SQL queries defined in a SQL file

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have an SQL file containing many SQL queries like so :

```
CREATE TABLE ..... ;
ALTER TABLE .... ;
```

I want to execute these queries in a single `spark.sql` call
How to achieve this in JAVA ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark doesn’t support executing multiple queries with a single call to `spark.sql` (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554032/issues-with-executing-multiple-queries-using-spark-and-hivesql)). If you don’t mind calling `spark.sql` multiple times, you can read  the `.sql` file into a string, split it into separate queries, and then pass it to `spark.sql`, like so:

```java
import java.nio.file.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] commands;

    try {
        Path sqlPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("query.sql");
        String sql = new String(Files.readAllBytes(sqlPath));
        commands = sql.split(";", 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("failed to read SQL file");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
        spark.sql(commands[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be just `spark.sql(sql)` ? why you are returning the execution of the queries into a Dataset?

Comment: HINT : semi-colons should be the delimiter between the SQL queries to execute.

Comment: updated to iterate through commands one at a time, split by `;`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question now.  Question says explicitly "in a single spark.sql call".

Comment: @CryptoFool `spark.sql()` doesn't support executing multiple queries in a single call, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554032/issues-with-executing-multiple-queries-using-spark-and-hivesql). Calling `spark.sql()` inside a loop accomplishes the task, it's just semantics.

Comment: the execution is actually returning a parsing exception : `mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'(', 'ADD', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CACHE', 'CLEAR', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DROP', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'FROM', 'GRANT', 'IMPORT', 'INSERT', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCK', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SELECT', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'TABLE', 'TRUNCATE', 'UNCACHE', 'UNLOCK', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'VALUES', 'WITH'}(line 2, pos 0)
`

Comment: @superhawk610 - well, then you should explain that in your answer.  The difference between `Q: How can I do A?  A: Do B` and `Q: How can I do A?  A: You can't, but you can do B` is significant.  The former leaves the original question hanging.  Your answer was otherwise a good one.  I'd suggest that you add the statement that you just made to me in your comment to the top of your answer.  (ps: it's more than semantics.  I assume that doing it all in one call would be more efficient.  Also, it's possible that due to context, doing two things in a single call vs two might give different results)

Comment: @marcnicole debugging your SQL file is up to you. A good first step would be to log out each SQL command before running it with `spark.sql` and make sure the syntax is valid, and that your queries are being correctly split as you’d expect.